# Firebase AngularFire Observables - Iterating over discussion list, grabbing user data based on author id, and returning aggregated data

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I'm building a comment section for a piece of my Angular 2 app, using Firebase, and all I'm doing is grabbing data from a `/request_discussions` tree table that contains a list of comments for a given discussion. All I'm trying to do is go through each discussion item and grab the author information from a `/users` tree table and aggregate them together so that it's one big "discussion" array.

The discussion object looks like:

`/request_discussions/<discussionID>`

```
{
   messageId1: {
     body: "Hello world",
     created_date: "2017-03-23T01:11:25.767Z",
     author_id: "authorId1"
   }
}
```

I'd like the object to look like:

```
{
   messageId1: {
     body: "Hello world",
     created_date: "2017-03-23T01:11:25.767Z",
     author_id: "authorId1",
     author: {
       $key: "authorId1",
       first_name: "Andrew",
       last_name: "Fussinger"
       ...<and all the other data>...
     }
   }
}
```

Here is my attempt at getting these observables to behave, but this is returning an array of arrays of objects that aren't anywhere near what I'm looking for.

```
getCheckRequestDiscussion(checkRequestId) {

    // Get request ID
    return this._af.database.list(`/request_discussions/${checkRequestId}`)
        .switchMap(messages => {

          return Observable.combineLatest(
            messages.map(message => {
              return this._af.database.list(`/users/${message.author_id}`)
            }),
            (...users) => {
              console.log('users?', users)
              return messages;
            }
          )
        })
  }
```

Does anyone know what I can do here to merge them together?

Answer (score 1):

Woops, so inside of the combineLatest obsevable, I'm doing a `.list`. I need to do a `.object`. Here is my updated code:

```
getCheckRequestDiscussion(checkRequestId) {

    // Get request ID
    return this._af.database.list(`/request_discussions/${checkRequestId}`)
        .switchMap(messages => {

          return Observable.combineLatest(
            messages.map(message => {
              return this._af.database.object(`/users/${message.author_id}`)
            }),
            (...users) => {
              messages.forEach((message, index) => {
                users.forEach(user => {
                  if(message.author_id === user.$key) {
                    messages[index]['author'] = user;
                  }
                })
              })
              return messages;
            }
          )
        })
  }
```